# Rails::Rack:LogTailer and Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, rack, unicorn

I'm switching from Thin to Unicorn. So far everything works and my tests are passing, but I'm not getting the useful log statements in my terminal. I have to `tail log/development.log` to see what actually happened.

I read http://dave.is/unicorn.html and was able to get it to work by diverting the log to STDOUT, but I'd like to be able to have my development log file as well, so I can `grep` it later.

How do I add Rails::Rack::LogTailer to get my log to also show up after I boot up my server?

Maybe I don't need Rails::Rack::LogTailer? I would like to not need to tail my log file after every request.

In case this is relevant ... I'm running Rails 3.2.13, Rack 1.4.5, and Unicorn 4.6.2.

--EDIT--

I tried adding this to the end of my `config/environments/development.rb`

`config.middleware.insert_after(Rails::Rack::Logger, Rails::Rack::LogTailer, "/log/development.log")`

But that didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix is very simple, delete leading "/".

Change: "/log/development.log"
To:      "log/development.log"

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't seem to work. No development.log file is created when I run my development server.

Comment: Strange because it works for me :). File log/development.log should be created when you start rails app (unicorn and this middleware has nothing to do with that).

Comment: I realize that I was doing something really dumb. I had   # config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  # config.logger.level = Logger.const_get(ENV['LOG_LEVEL'] ? ENV['LOG_LEVEL'].upcase : 'DEBUG') in my development.rb